# How can I make itemgetter to take input from list variable?

Tags: python, operator-keyword

How can I use itemgetter with list variable instead of integers?
For example:

```
from operator import itemgetter
z = ['foo', 'bar','qux','zoo']
id = [1,3]
```

I have no problem doing this:

```
In [5]: itemgetter(1,3)(z)
Out[5]: ('bar', 'zoo')
```

But it gave error when I do this:

```
In [7]: itemgetter(id)(z)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-7ba47b19f282> in <module>()
----> 1 itemgetter(id)(z)

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

How can I make itemgetter to take input from list variable correctly, i.e. using `id`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you do:

```
print itemgetter(id)(z)
```

you are passing a `list` to `itemgetter`, while it expects indices (integers).

**What can you do?** You can unpack the `list` using `*`:

```
print itemgetter(*id)(z)
```

to visualize this better, both following calls are equivalent:

```
print itemgetter(1, 2, 3)(z)
print itemgetter(*[1, 2, 3])(z)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
>>> indices = [1,3]
>>> itemgetter(*indices)(z)
('bar', 'zoo')
```

And don't use `id` as a variable name, it's a built-in function.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

`itemgetter(*id)(z)` will get what you want as already pointed out by Awini Haudhary. Unpacking a dict can be useful too in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is, `itemgetter` expects the list of items to be passed, as individual arguments, but you are passing a single list. So, you can unpack like in [Aशwini चhaudhary's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22903783/1903116), or you can [`apply`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply) the ids, like this

```
print apply(itemgetter, ids)(z)
# ('bar', 'zoo')
```

**Note:** `apply` is actually deprecated. Always prefer unpacking. I mentioned `apply` just for the sake of completeness.